# UpdateProgress not closing when a query takes a long time

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, updateprogress

I am using the UpdateProgress ASP.NET control along with an UpdatePanel to get some data via a web service, update some content locally and show a spinner whilst doing so.

The problem is that when the web service call takes a long time the spinner won't disapear (as if it fell asleep listening for the async postback response). The content will update locally (I can see the changes in the DB) but the spinner won't go until I refresh the page.

p.s When the data is small, this works perfectly and the spinner stops when the process finishes.

Is there a timeout option I should be setting or something?

EDIT: I am using error handling on the page and spit out any errors encountered in a JS alert box. Also, the method is designed to roll back DB transactions if it encounters an error which doesn't happen.

Comment: You probably had an error and you are not handling the error condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UpdateProgress timeout is controlled via the AsyncPostBackTimeout on your page's script manager (or master page if script manager is located there). You can set this to zero for no timeout.

Comment: the default timeout is 90 seconds so if your query is longer than that there may be some consequence of events causing your issue

Comment: The routines just take a long time sometimes depending on what information is being exported. I did have the value set to some random high number but I guess that wasn't enough. 0 did the job instead.